# can't use case as new_c in having or where condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I'm trying to use **CASE** in  PostgreSQL query and use it in where or having condition and i got this error message

> [Err] ERROR:  column "new_dismiss" does not exist LINE 14:
>   trans_requistion_details.original_qty > new_dismiss

```
SELECT
*,
    CASE
        WHEN dismiss_qty is NULL THEN 0
        ELSE dismiss_qty
    END AS new_dismiss

FROM
 trans_requistion_details
INNER JOIN  sub_ingredients ON  trans_requistion_details.sub_ing_id =  sub_ingredients.sub_ing_id
INNER JOIN  units ON  sub_ingredients.sub_ing_stock_unit =  units.unit_id
INNER JOIN  ing_groups ON  sub_ingredients.ing_group_id =  ing_groups.ing_group_id
 HAVING
 trans_requistion_details.trans_id = 175991 and original_qty > new_dismiss
```

Comment: You need a subquery, CTE, or lateral join.

Comment: Use the same case in HAVING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [`CTE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)

```
WITH j AS (
  SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN dismiss_qty is NULL THEN 0
    ELSE dismiss_qty END AS new_dismiss
FROM trans_requistion_details
) SELECT * FROM j
INNER JOIN  sub_ingredients ON  j.sub_ing_id =  sub_ingredients.sub_ing_id
INNER JOIN  units ON  sub_ingredients.sub_ing_stock_unit =  units.unit_id
INNER JOIN  ing_groups ON  sub_ingredients.ing_group_id =  ing_groups.ing_group_id
WHERE j.trans_id = 175991 and original_qty > j.new_dismiss
```

Comment: thnks ,, this code is working good